# How to use Azure DDoS with App Service Plan

Tags: azure, ddos

Is it possible to use Azure DDoS with an Azure App Service Environment or Plan? Everything I've seen relates to vnets but my Service Environment/Plan states

> Your app is in an App Service Environment which is already in a Vnet and does not require use of VNet Integration to access resources in that VNet. The only reason to use this feature is if you need to access resources in another VNet that is not otherwise connected to your ASE VNet.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation on DDOS protection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ddos-protection-overview) indicates that you cannot apply this to an ASE:

> Policies are applied to public IP addresses associated to resources
>   deployed in virtual networks, such as Azure Load Balancer, Azure
>   Application Gateway, and Azure Service Fabric instances, but this
>   protection **does not apply to App Service Environments**

Comment: Ah I missed that! I will have to look into adding an app gateway on top of the ASE. Thanks!